# Override specified on a non-overriding method

Tags: apex, trigger, oop

I am trying to play around with creating a base Trigger handler class that each trigger type can extend. I wanted to pass the trigger types into the base class as a member variable and then be able to use them in child classes.

I am currently getting errors of 'over-ride specified on non-overriding method.' I have not been able to find much about this but I am assuming it is related to using generic SObjects in the base class?

Base class

```
public virtual with sharing class   TriggerHandler{
    public List<SObject> newTrigger {get; set;}
    public List<SObject> oldTrigger {get; set;}
    public Map<Id, SObject> newMap {get; set;}
    public Map<Id, SObject> oldMap {get; set;}
    public TriggerOperation type {get; set;}

    public TriggerHandler(List<SObject> newTrigger, Map<Id, SObject> newMap, List<SObject> oldTrigger, Map<Id, SObject> oldMap, TriggerOperation type){
        this.newTrigger = newTrigger; this.newMap = newMap; this.oldTrigger = oldTrigger; this.oldMap = oldMap; this.type = type;       
    }   

    public virtual void onBeforeInsert(){}

    public virtual void  onBeforeUpdate(){}

    public virtual void onAfterInsert(){}

    public  virtual void onAfterUpdate(Map<Id, SObject> existingRecords){}

    public virtual void onDelete(){}

    public  virtual void handleOnInsert(){}

    public virtual  void handleOnUpdate(){}

    public virtual void handleOnAfterInsert(){}

}
```

child class

```
public with sharing class ContactTriggerHandler extends TriggerHandler{

    public ContactTriggerHandler(List<Contact> newList, Map<Id, Contact> newMap, List<Contact> oldList, Map<Id, Contact> oldMap, TriggerOperation type){
        super(newList, newMap, oldList, oldMap, type);
        System.debug('Contact Trigger handler created');
    }
    public override void onBeforeInsert(List<Contact> newTrigger){
        System.debug('On before Insert called from Contact Trigger Handler');
        System.debug('values in new trigger are' +  newTrigger);
    }
    public override void onBeforeUpdate( ){
        System.debug('On before Update called from Contact Trigger Handler');
    }

}
```

Trigger

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (before insert, before update, before delete, after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {
    ContactTriggerHandler handler = new ContactTriggerHandler(Trigger.new, Trigger.newMap, Trigger.old, Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.operationType);
}
```

Comment: If you dont wanna re-invent the wheel you can use Kevin O'Hara's trigger framework:
https://github.com/kevinohara80/sfdc-trigger-framework

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your signature for `onBeforeInsert` in base class and child class does not match. That is the reason you are getting the error which you are getting.

Changing the below line in base class

```
public virtual void onBeforeInsert(){}
```

to

```
public virtual void onBeforeInsert(List<sObject> newRecords){}
```

should do the trick.

Also, one more thing you need to correct is the way you are passing the values to the `onBeforeInsert` method. In the base class, it mentions that it will accept `List<sObject>` which is a generic object and you are passing `List<Contact>` which is a concrete object. Due to this, it is not matching the signature and hence giving you the error. You should pass `List<sObject>` instead of `List<Contact>` and then you can typecast it to the concrete class whenever you are using it.

```
public override void onBeforeInsert(List<sObject> newTrigger){
    System.debug('On before Insert called from Contact Trigger Handler');
    System.debug('values in new trigger are' +  newTrigger);
    System.debug('Typecasted values ' (List<Contact>) newTrigger)
}
```

Comment: I made that change but I am still getting the error.

Comment: @BrooksJohnson I tried same code it works agter making parent class's `onBeforeInsert` to accept List<Sobject>

Comment: @BrooksJohnson As mentioned by Pranay, it worked for me as well, only difference I identified is the way you are calling the method. Updated the answer with the information. That should help you.

Comment: Thank you for the help with this. @PranayJaiswal this is less of an attempt to reinvent the wheel and more my trying to get some OO practice in.  I thought override would let me change the signature as well. Thank you for the link.